# how to convert decimal to 8 bit binary

Tags: c++, binary

```
int a[9],b[9],i;
  for(i=0; num>0; i++)
  {
    a[i]=num%2;
    num= num/2;
  }
```

I am working on decimal to binary conversion. I can convert themi want answer in 8 bits. And it gives me as, for example x =5, so output will be 101, but i want 00000101. Is there any way to append zeros in the start of array, without using any library.

Comment: is you using string type variable in record[i].name variable?

Comment: yes sir record is array object of class . class has string attribute of name .                                      class health_clinic
{
private:
    string name;
    string email;
    string p_no;
    float weight;
    float height;}

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you have read something (maybe a char or a number) from cin directly before calling this function, but you forgot the `cin.ignore()` to consume the `' \n'` that ended the previous input and that was not read by your previous read.

Answer (score 0):

The health clinic manages patients and the patient manages their own data.

You can run/check this code in https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/StdGetLine#main.cpp

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Patient
{
private:
    std::string phoneNumber;
    std::string name;
    std::string email;
    float weight;
    float height;

public:
    void SetName(const std::string &name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }

    void SetEmail(const std::string &email)
    {
        this->email = email;
    }

    void SetPhoneNumber(const std::string &phoneNumber)
    {
        this->phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    void SetWeight(const float &weight)
    {
        this->weight = weight;
    }

    void SetHeight(const float &height)
    {
        this->height = height;
    }

    std::string GetName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    std::string GetEmail()
    {
        return this->email;
    }

    std::string GetPhoneNumber()
    {
        return this->phoneNumber;
    }

    float GetWeight()
    {
        return this->weight;
    }

    float GetHeight()
    {
        return this->height;
    }

public:
};

class HealtClinic
{
private:
    std::vector<Patient> patients;

public:
    void AddPatient()
    {
        Patient p;
        std::cout << "\nEnter name : ";
        std::string sdata;
        std::getline(std::cin, sdata);
        p.SetName(sdata);

        std::cout << "\nEnter email : ";
        std::getline(std::cin, sdata);
        p.SetEmail(sdata);

        std::cout << "Enter phone number : ";
        std::getline(std::cin, sdata);
        p.SetPhoneNumber(sdata);

        int idata;
        std::cout << "Enter weight in kg : ";
        std::cin >> idata;
        p.SetWeight(idata);

        std::cout << "Enter height in meters: ";
        std::cin >> idata;
        p.SetHeight(idata);

        patients.push_back(p);
    }

    void ShowPatients()
    {
        std::cout << "--- PATIENTS ---" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < patients.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "--- " << i << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Name: " << patients[i].GetName() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Email: " << patients[i].GetEmail() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Phone number: " << patients[i].GetPhoneNumber() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Weight: " << patients[i].GetWeight() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Height: " << patients[i].GetHeight() << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    HealtClinic clinic;
    clinic.AddPatient();
    clinic.ShowPatients();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter name : Joma

Enter email : joma@email.com
Enter phone number : 123456789
Enter weight in kg : 88
Enter height in meters: 1.8
--- PATIENTS ---
--- 0
Name: Joma
Email: joma@email.com
Phone number: 123456789
Weight: 88
Height: 1
```

[image]